# How does measurement work in this Multi qbit entangled system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, measurements

Given a 4 qbit entangled state: $C_1= 1/2 (|0000\rangle+|1100\rangle+|0011\rangle-|1111\rangle)$.

Assuming we take one particle, and measure them it in the basis: $1/\sqrt2(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)$, $1/\sqrt2(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)$

then we take another particle and measure it too in the same basis.

What would the resultant state of the entangled system be in each stage?

I assume we can write the above system in the form:

($1/\sqrt2(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)(|00\rangle/\sqrt2)+1/\sqrt2(|00\rangle-|11\rangle (|11\rangle/\sqrt2)$

But I am unclear beyond this.

P.S. New to QM and don't have much idea with 4 qubit systems. Can someone help with the steps in multi qbit examples, preferably using matrix operators for this specific case and how to measure in a general case? Most sources only talk about 2 qbit systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measurement in the $|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$ and $|-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)$  can be expressed in terms of a Von-Neumann measurement. i.e, probability of an observable i for a projective valued measurement is given by,

$$P_i = tr(\rho \Pi_i),  $$

where $\lbrace\Pi_i\rbrace$ is the set of projection operators of the measurement and $\rho$ is the density matrix. For such measurements the post measurement state for the i$^{th}$ outcome is given by,
$$ \rho' = \frac{\Pi_i \rho \Pi_i}{tr(\rho\Pi_i)}$$

Now for the case asked in the question, the projection operators in the $|+/-\rangle$ basis would be $\Pi_+ = |+\rangle\langle+|$, $\Pi_- = |-\rangle\langle-|$. In order to measure just a subsystem, for example the second qubit of the four qubits, the operator has to be tensored with identity.

$$\Pi_+ = I_2\otimes \Pi_+ \otimes I_2 \otimes I_2$$

Comment: thank you for the answer. but as i said i am new to QM. so I am struggling with the answer. would it be possible if you can explain this specific case explicitly. The state of the system must be an explicit state in each of the two steps (as in the Q). And there are just 4 qbits to be measured. so the end system must be in some specific state in each of the case. That is what I am interested in. Can you please clarify?

Comment: let us assume we operate on first two particles..

Comment: In the case of entangled systems, measurements on one of the systems collapses the system to whichever state it gets measured in. Hence there is no specific (pure) state that the answer can be written in. It will be a probabilistic mixture of states, called a mixed state. Such states cannot be written in the bra-ket notation, but as a density matrix. The density matrix can be found out with the equation given in the answer (post measurement state).